# window.print shows more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample script to print a part of my website page when the button is clicked. 
But the strange thing is that when I transition use ajax to transition and click the same button window.print activates two times, and if I press 3 times, 3 window.print shows up and it keeps going on and on. How to prevent window.print to show only once even after transitioning to the different page with ajax? Some examples or hints will be great! I would love to here from you!

```
$(function(){
        $('.printButton').live('click', function(){
            var printPage = $('.printarea').html();
            $('body').append('<div id="print"></div>');
            $('#print').append(printPage);
            $('body > :not(#print)').addClass('print_off');
            window.print();
            $('#print').remove();
            $('.print_off').removeClass('print_off');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please post a working snippet of your code. That would be faster to debug.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated

Comment: To know the jQuery version you use, `console.log($.fn.jquery);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your event is getting binded again and again to the button. You can try following. Also, use `on` as `live` is deprecated.

```
$('.printButton').off('click');
$('.printButton').on('click', function(){
       var printPage = $('.printarea').html();
       $('body').append('<div id="print"></div>');
       $('#print').append(printPage);
       $('body > :not(#print)').addClass('print_off');
       window.print();
       $('#print').remove();
       $('.print_off').removeClass('print_off');
});
```

For reference, [jQuery.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: My jquery version is 1.5.2, what should I do? And I don't want to update it.

Comment: Then in place of `$('.printButton').off('click');`, you can use `$('.printButton').die('click');` and can leave rest of the code as it is. For reference, https://api.jquery.com/die/

Comment: @Tony: there is a loop somewhere. I think you have a click handler that sets itself. again. It's a logical issue related to code you didn't post.

Comment: Seems like I was missing the window.die!